# What are the differences between karma reporters?

Tags: karma-runner, karma-coverage

I am looking at karma's reporter configuration.

There are some possible reporters: progress, dots, growl, coverage. I don't find any detailed information explaining each of the options.

I tried progress and dots, they all print log to console, the result looks the same. What are the differences between them?

Growl, coverage need a little more configuration, so I didn't succeed testing them.

Comment: There are some others I would like to mention here too: `kjhtml`, 'teamcity'.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

- Progress will show the number of tests executed, skipped and total.
- dots will print a dot for each test executed
- growl will use the [growl tool](http://growl.info/) to report the progress of the testing.
  Note: you need to install [the plugin](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-growl-reporter) to use this guy.
- coverage works together with [the coverage pre-processor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage) to generate an HTML Coverage report of your Javascript files.
  Note: you need to install [the plugin](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage) to use this guy.